# Show hide HTML code based on keywords not working

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I've created basic code for showing/hiding code based on keywords, but it's not working. Why? I've tried in many ways, but not working. It always shows though it doesn't meet the conditions.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dateKeyword = "[aaa]";
  if ($('body:contains("' + dateKeyword + '")').length > 0) {
    $("#date").show();
    $("#current-date").text(new Date().toDateString());
  } else {
    $("#date").hide();
  }
  var mnKeyword = "(kk-aka)";
  if ($('body:contains("' + mnKeyword + '")').length > 0) {
    $("#mn").show();
  } else {
    $("#mn").hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2 id="date" style="display:none;">Date: <span id="current-date"></span></h2>
<h2 id="mn" style="display:none;">Upcoming Event: Asia Cup 2030</h2>
```

Comment: Are you putting this script inside of the HTML that you are searching?

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `$('body:contains("WHATEVER")').length` is always `1`.

Try to refine your selector and nest your content in a `<main>` element.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dateKeyword = "Date";
  if ($('main:contains("' + dateKeyword + '")').length) {
    $("#date").show();
    $("#current-date").text(new Date().toDateString());
  } else {
    $("#date").hide();
  }
  var mnKeyword = "Asia";
  if ($('main:contains("' + mnKeyword + '")').length) {
    $("#mn").show();
  } else {
    $("#mn").hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<main>
  <h2 id="date" style="display:none;">Date: <span id="current-date"></span></h2>
  <h2 id="mn" style="display:none;">Upcoming Event: Asia Cup 2030</h2>
</main>
```

Comment: What you did @Mr. Polywhirl. It Should be like that, if keywords are available inside body or main, "h2" tags will be show. Otherwise they'll remain hide.

Comment: @Mr. Polywhirl, wrong answer. I think You're unable to catch his words.